# как вывести элементы массива в несколько рядов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть массив вида arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] как вывести его в виде

```
1 | 4 | 7 |10
-------------
2 | 5 | 8 |
-------------
3 | 6 | 9 |

<script>
//набросал немного кода,но это определенно не то
$(document).append('<table>');
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   $(document).append('<tr>');
if(arr[i]%3){
     $(document).append('<td>arr[i]</td>');
}
   $(document).append('</tr>');
}
$(document).append('</table>');
</script>
```

Comment: array chunk тебе в помощь :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: Предлагаю выпилить все что относится к JS и сделать вопрос чисто алгоритмическим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container"></div>
<script>
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var c = 3; // изменяемый параметр количества элементов в чанке
var new_arr = [];
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i+=c) {
    new_arr.push(arr.slice(i,i+c));
}
html = '<table>';
for(i=0; i<c; i++){
    html+='<tr>';
    for(j=0;j<arr.length/c;j++){
        if(typeof new_arr[j][i] != 'undefined'){
            html+='<td>'+new_arr[j][i]+'</td>';
        }
    }
    html+='</tr>';
}
$('.container').html(html);
</script>
```

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/7osjxc6r/)